# Capturing data from a script

Tags: javascript, csv

I'm using a simple "Roll The Dice" script. I'm running into some brick walls when trying to save the results of the roll.

Is there any way for me to save the results of the dice roll? CSV is probably the easiest choice with the headers for the columns being "Date" "Name" "Result".

I need this to run without any special server side stuff, its simply html stored on a shared network drive, I don't have full admin access to.

Thanks for any advice!

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I could potentially have the dice roll result added to a form and then the form data written to CSV. So maybe this could be simplified?

Comment: Please clarify: Is this a Java question or a JavaScript question? You mention one in the body of the question and the other in your tags, and I'm sure that you know that they're entirely different languages.

Comment: How about showing what have you tried and where it goes wrong?

Comment: I have only tried PHP but that needs more than what I can do. I have no idea how to do it, that's why I'm here!  The dice roll itself is javascript.

Comment: [tag:java] tag removed and [tag:javascript] tag added. Please be more careful with your tagging since if done correctly it's the best way to get the right experts to your question. If done incorrectly, it only serves to confuse folks who otherwise would help you.

Comment: Would [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) be an option? I think that is the simplest way to store data in JS. You wouldn't be able to write to a file via JS, but you could output a string representation of the data into a textarea/div and copy/paste it into a file

Comment: Extra note: I may be wrong about not being able to save files in JS, but you might require a modern browser to do so (and domain policies might bite you in the butt), but look around for that after you get JSON down.

Comment: Its not a duplicate, that other question asks how to do it with an external script. I'm trying to do this without any external references, just anything that can be done natively in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

*********** **EDIT** **********

If you're trying to actually access the filesystem via your javascript I'm afraid you're out of luck .JS in the browser is prevented from accessing the filesystem in any way as a security feature. *Therefore there can be no persistent storage on your network drive.* The only way to do that would be to have some kind of server on a machine that has access to the network drive. If all you want to do is create a file for each user to download then this is the way

********** **End edit** **********

Well, lacking a response including code I've come up with this solution: [(fiddle link)](http://jsfiddle.net/3v8s2q8a/1/).

Here's the custom code:

```
var log = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#roll').click(function () {
        if (!$('#name').val()) {
            alert("Enter your name first.");
            return;
        }
        var data = {
            Date: Date.now(),
            Name: $('#name').val(),
            Result: (Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1)
        };
        if (data === '') { return; }
        else {
            log.push(data);
            $('#rollLog').append('<tr><td>' + data.Date + '</td><td>' + data.Name + '</td><td>' + data.Result + '</td></tr>');
        }
    });

    $('#save').click(function () {
        JSONToCSVConvertor(log, "Roll Log", true);
    });
});
```

The other function can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/hybrid13i/JXrwM/

Basically what's happening here is we're creating and storing your data in an array of javascript objects which is directly translatable to JSON (as per comment by Esaevian). Then we use this nice function to parse that JSON into a CSV array and open it in a new window, your browser then interprets this as a downloadable file and wala! you are able to download the information.

Comment: This does seem like a great idea! My only concern is that the file has to be saved. I want to have a central .csv file that is written to with the info as it is added.

Comment: Ahh, then the answer is no. You can't do that with JS, not in the browser anyway. The browser has protections that prevent you from touching the filesystem. So this answer is as close as you'll get. Without some kind of server you just can't do it. Sorry :\